# AspxGridView paging problem

Tags: devexpress, paging, aspxgridview

I have an AspxGridView on my page and i set its DataSource on button's click. When the user clicks the button, i call a method to set its DataSource and DataBind() it. PageSize property is set to 5 but paging is not working. What can i do to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the following article.  It explains why this problem appears and how to fix it:

[Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/K18183.aspx)